# Error Validating SSIS Package When Attempting to Run in 32 Bit Mode Within SSMS

Tags: ssis, ssms, ssms-2016

I have a SSIS package that is currently deployed to my SSISDB. This package is required to run in 32Bit mode and does fine when I change the '64BitRuntime' setting to false within SSDT.

My issue comes about when I try to run it in 32 bit mode after it has been deployed to my SSISDB. My error occurs at the following screen: 
[image]

The accompanying error is as follows:

> The path for 'ISServerExec.exe' cannot be found. The operation will now exit.
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "validate_package_internal": 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The path for 'ISServerExec.exe' cannot be found. The operation will now exit.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQuerySmi(Boolean sendToPipe)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteToPipe(SmiContext pipeContext)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlPipe.ExecuteAndSend(SqlCommand command)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.RaiseError(SysMessageId messageId, SysMessageSeverity severity, Object[] args)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.ValidatePackageInternal(SqlInt64 projectId, SqlInt64 package_id, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 validationId, SqlString targetEnvironment, SqlInt16 use32BitRuntime)
>   . (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27108)

How can I work through this issue? the only thing I'm finding through Google are how to mark the checkbox...

Answer (score 0):

if you upgrade SQL recently, it may be issue with paths stored in ssisdb catalog. in my case, drop & create new catalog & deploy project, fixed Error 27108 while executing package from stored procedure.
hope it helps.